# C# Console Application console Input and Listen to Handlers

Tags: c#, event-handling, console-application, console-input

I have a Skype for Business bot that is listening to a specific contact with handlers from the lync sdk.
Now I want to input some commands through the console.
But when I use the ReadLine method my Bot only listen to the console and not to the skype handler from the conversation. Is there a way to listen to both inputs?

Best regards

Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run bot at new thread, like this:

```
var bot = new MyBot();
new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => {
    bot.Start();
}).Start();
do {
    Console.ReadLine();//read command
} while (true);
```